# How to run and install files in directory inside /opt in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi I have installed ubuntu in virtual box and I downloaded petalinux2017.1 into downloads directory and moved the run file into a directory called PetaLinux in opt in my root directory.

But i couldnot run the file when my commands are in the following way and it is showing an error "command not found".

```
my@my-Ubuntu: /opt/PetaLinux$petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run
```

i tried the same with sudo and the error is same and i want to install it into the directory PetaLinux and I am a beginner in these.

Comment: Also see [Why do I have to use sh to execute scripts from CD/DVD media?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59561/56041) on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). `sudo bash ./petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run` should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you put this into /opt/?

Whatever, try this:

```
$ cd /opt/PetaLinux
$ sudo chmod +x petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run
$ ./petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run
```

Comment: No got denied permissions so deleted the directory PetaLinux in the opt and the source is now located in my downloads folder only. What should be done? to install it into a directory in opt?

Comment: Ok, it's make easier for us. Try `cd /your/download-folder`, `chmod +x petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run` and `sudo ./petalinux-v2015.4-final-installer-dec.run /opt/PetaLinux`.

Comment: *"Why you put this into /opt/..."* - You should ask questions in the comments.

Comment: The install is failing at the final step saying it can't be installed in a root directory, I want to run it in the home directory and used the following commands `chmod +x petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run` and `petalinux-v2017.1-final-installer.run /home/my/Petalinux` and an error command not found is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands :

```
cd /opt/PetaLinux
sudo chmod 777 PetaLinux$petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run
./Petalinux-v2017.1-finalinstaller.run
```

Comment: Do not give everyone in your system the permission to modify executables. Use `chmod 755` if you follow this approach.